# Can this question be unprotected?

Tags: support, specific-question

After some deliberation, I approved [this edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37462) to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47401/is-amy-pond-claras-grandmother/47402), although I considered rejecting it for being too radical a change.

It should have been a separate answer in its own right. However, this was made by a new user and the question is protected, so the user would need at least 10 rep earned on this stack.

**Can this question be de-protected?** Then the user can turn their edit into a separate answer, possibly earning some rep and becoming a valuable and respected user on this stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It collected 3 non-answers over a space of 3 months.  That doesn't strike me as a huge magnet for problem answers.  I think it should be unprotected, and if it does prove problematic, we can always re-protect it later.

Answer (score 3):

I've unprotected it, despite the obvious potential for them to get more rep than me and end up making me look bad.